# Jump to method call from method definition in eclipse [Java perspective]

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, keyboard-shortcuts

(In eclipse)
We have a shortcut key to jump to method definition from wherever the method is called, i.e. by using F3. But what if I am currently on the method definition and I want to go that location where the method is called or used. Any shortcut for this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can try `Ctrl+Shift+G` which is a equivalent to find references.

or `Ctrl+Alt+H` which brings up call hierarchy.

Comment: It's `Cmd+Shift+G` on a Mac, very useful!

Comment: Cmd+O seems to be what it's set to by default now in eclipse luna-

Answer (score 8):

It's `Ctrl + Alt + H` to bring up the call hierarchy.